# C++ equivalent to Python's "if x in [string1, string2, …]"

Tags: c++, string

My mini project is to make a chatbot; I have not google open sources, nor have I researched how to build. I'm trying this as to see how well I understand C++: Saying that;

I'm trying to make a "Box" of sort in which holds all "questions" that can be given and seeing "if" that "question" is "in" the "Box" it'll execute said code.

In Python it would be more or less:

```
Box = ["Yes", "YES", "yes", "yEs", "YeS", "yES"]

print "Will you be working today?"
response = raw_input("> ")
if response in Box:
    print "Very well, then how can I assist you?"
```

So how would I go about doing so in C++. Or what is it called in C++? An array? A list? Vector? It's a bit confusing to differentiate those in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this I would consider converting the response to all lower-case then doing a straight comparison:

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

// convert string to lowercase
std::string lower_case(std::string s)
{
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin()
        , std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::tolower));
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string response;

    // ask question and get response

    // now you don't need to look at every combination
    if(lower_case(response) == "yes")
    {
        // positive response code
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Comment: even in Python, making the string lowercase then compare is better

Comment: Yeah, I know that, though I just wanted to make it clear. XD Such a clutz! Thanks anyways.

Comment: Wow, you guys quickly answered my questions. You and everyone else. Thank you! @Galik

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this, requires `<string>`, `<vector>` and `<algorithm>`:

```
vector<string> box = { "yes"...};
//get input
if(std::find(box.begin(), box.end(), search_str) != box.end()) {
    //found
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be simpler and slightly more expressive if you just take the input case-insensitively.

```
std::string downcased(std::string s) {
  std::locale loc{"en_US.UTF-8"};
  std::transform(begin(s), end(s), begin(s), [&](auto const& c) {
    return std::tolower(c, loc);
  });
  return s;
}
```

So you'd then do

```
if(downcased(input_string) == "yes") ...
```

and there is no "box" to deal with.

If you have Boost installed then you can do without the `downcased()` function:

```
if(boost::algorithm::to_lower_copy(input_string) == "yes") ...
```

That said, C++ does have C's primitive arrays. These are similar to Python's lists in use, but they are static, meaning they don't change their, and they don't hold their size as a datum somewhere. C++ also offers `std::vector<>` in the standard library. This is a template class expressing a dynamic array that can change its size, and does so automatically for the most part. That, with algortithms such as `std::find()`, do the trick. For instance,

```
std::vector<std::string> const ys = {"yes", "yEs", };  // &c
if(std::find(begin(ys), end(ys), "yeS") != end(ys))
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing the input to lower case and just testing against "yes" is by far the simplest solution, but a more general case can be done with [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

A set is an ordered structure made for high speed, "Is X in here?" look ups. It's similar to the std::vector suggested by others, but the vector requires a linear search.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{

    std::string input;

    std::cin >> input;

    std::set<std::string> box{"Yes", "YES", "yes", "yEs", "YeS", "yES"};

    if (box.find(input) != box.end())
    {
        std::cout << "Very well, then how can I assist you?" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can expect your experience with data structures in C++ to differ from Python quite a bit. Where Python has a single `list` class which is the go-to choice for most of your container needs, C++ has several container data structures. C-style arrays, `std::array`, `std::list`, and `std::vector` are all possibilities. `std::vector` tends to be the go-to option for ordinary lists.

That said, if all you're trying to do is to test repeatedly for membership strings in a set, you should use a set data structure instead, rather than doing a linear search on a list. The equivalent of Python's `set` class in C++11 would be `std::unordered_set` (they're both implemented as hash tables).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {
  std::unordered_set<std::string> box = {"Yes", "YES", "yes"};
  std::string input;
  std::getline(std::cin, input);
  if(box.count(input)) {
    std::cout << "Very well, then how can I assist you?\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Your advice is not correct in all cases: for small sets a linear scan of a list is likely to be fastest.